# Erro na exportação de uma base de dados usando o mysql Workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

Essa é minha primeira vez utilizando o Mysql WORKBENCH, estou tendo problemas quando vou exportar um banco. Na imagem abaixo são os parametros que configurei na aba Data Export antes de começar o processo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando clico em exportar o processo é encerrado com os seguintes erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de saber como resolver esses problemas, já procurei na internet mas nenhuma solução resolveu o meu problema especifico. O que seria essa  "unknown variable 'order-by-primary" e como resolver o erro 1045 de acesso negado?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: editei, pra tentar deixar mais claro